# What does "to hit" mean?

Tags: meaning

A: What's that? (B gives A a book)

B: Anton Bjornberg, the hottest writer `to hit` Sweden since Stieg Larsson.

can I define it as popular? I guess it has similar meaning with hit song. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Basically it means "arrive in".  Things have been different since Jack the Knife *hit* town.  Mary Smith really *hit* the big time since she released her last album.

Comment: it simply means "to arrive on the scene" or "to arrive in a milieu".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *does not* mean popular. The only reason there is a connotation of popularity in that sentence is because of the use of ["hottest"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hot#Adjective). To hit here means, to quote the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hit):

> 4. Reach (a particular level, point, or figure)
>
> 4.2 Arrive at or go to (a place)
>
> 4.3 (Of a product) become available and make an impact on

(See section 4. The subsections there are relevant.)

If Bjornberg is the most hottest writer to hit Sweden since Larsson, he is the most popular (or perhaps the best, depending on context) writer to reach the Swedish book market since Larsson.

Comment: Maroon - It means 4. Reach (a particular level, point, or figure) right? First I  thought "4.2 Arrive at or go to (a place)" for these "REACH" explanation.

Comment: @seemunTeh: The subpoints 4.2 and 4.3 are elaborations of 4. In the context of your sentence, yes, but all of the sections I cited seem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. The sentence could also have been, "EL James, the worst writer to hit America since Stephanie Meyer." Here are two definitions, which, combined, give you an idea of what "hit" means in this context:

```
1. to have a marked effect or influence on; affect severely
2. to arrive in
```

Basically, in this case, "to hit" means "to reach."